# How Do I Get The Hisory Of A LinearState

Tags: corda

The output of one of my flows is a LinearState that has been "modified" over time by various flows.

Is there an API to get the previous versions of this state in the order that they were created/modified?

I can query the vault like this:

```
    val linearIdCriteria = QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(linearId = listOf(outputState.linearId), status = ALL)
    val states = myNode.services.vaultService.queryBy<MyState>(linearIdCriteria).states
```

However, the SQL generated by hibernate doesn't have an `Order By` clause so the order of the states in the list [cannot be guaranteed](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/queries-order.html).

The states returned don't have any timestamp on them so I can't see how to order the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time that the state was saved is available as a sorting option (`Sort.VaultStateAttribute.RECORDED_TIME`) which should guarantee the order of the vault query.

```
//Get all versions of the State by its LinearId
val linearIdCriteria = QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(linearId = listOf(outputState.linearId), status = ALL)

//Add sorting by recorded date
val sortByRecordedDate = SortColumn(SortAttribute.Standard(Sort.VaultStateAttribute.RECORDED_TIME), Sort.Direction.ASC)
val sorting = Sort(listOf(sortByRecordedDate))

val states = myNode.services.vaultService.queryBy<MyState>(linearIdCriteria, sorting).states
```

Answer (score -1):

Unconsumed and consumed states can be sorted in ascending/descending alphabetical order using the following code -

```
Vault.StateStatus status = Vault.StateStatus.CONSUMED;
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Set<Class<LinearState>> contractStateTypes = new HashSet(singletonList(LinearState.class));

QueryCriteria vaultCriteria = new VaultQueryCriteria(status, contractStateTypes);

List<UniqueIdentifier> linearIds = singletonList(ids.getSecond());
QueryCriteria linearCriteriaAll = new LinearStateQueryCriteria(null, linearIds, Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED, null);
QueryCriteria dealCriteriaAll = new LinearStateQueryCriteria(null, null, dealIds);

QueryCriteria compositeCriteria1 = dealCriteriaAll.or(linearCriteriaAll);
QueryCriteria compositeCriteria2 = compositeCriteria1.and(vaultCriteria);

PageSpecification pageSpec = new PageSpecification(DEFAULT_PAGE_NUM, MAX_PAGE_SIZE);
Sort.SortColumn sortByUid = new Sort.SortColumn(new SortAttribute.Standard(Sort.LinearStateAttribute.UUID), Sort.Direction.DESC);
Sort sorting = new Sort(ImmutableSet.of(sortByUid));
Vault.Page<LinearState> results = vaultService.queryBy(LinearState.class, compositeCriteria2, pageSpec, sorting);
```

OR

```
   val sortAttribute = SortAttribute.Custom(CustomerSchema.CustomerEntity.class,
 "changeDate")
     val sorter = Sort(setOf(Sort.SortColumn(sortAttribute, Sort.Direction.DESC)))
     val constraintResults = vaultService.queryBy<LinearState>(constraintTypeCriteria, sorter)
```

Following are the URLs for reference:

URL1: https://docs.corda.net/api-vault-query.html

URL2: https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/5060

URL3: https://github.com/manosbatsis/vaultaire

URL4: https://r3-cev.atlassian.net/browse/CORDA-2247

Comment: How does sorting alphabetically help me sort the states by version?

Comment: If the states definition have a "versionDate" column you can create a sortAttribute using that column. ----- 
"val sortAttribute = SortAttribute.Custom(xxSchema1.xx.class,
 "versionDate")"

Comment: They don't have a versionDate column though.

Comment: You would have to define a column that stores date in your schema, This column can be used for sorting.  
For example in the following - the Customer Schema has "changeDate" column using which sortAttribute is formed.

" val sortAttribute = SortAttribute.Custom(CustomerSchema.CustomerEntity.class,
 "changeDate")"

Similarly, you can define a column "versionDate" (for example) that will have dates of the states.

Comment: Downvoted because it requires custom schema changes